# Building project .Net native toolchain enabled results in Internal compiler error: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a solution with 3 projects plus one packaging project, and one of the projects is refusing to build - but only for release. Debug is fine. The project is called Foreground, with the namespace ForeGsp containing the class App in App.xaml.cd and in MainPage.xaml.cs there is the class MainPage and Item. Now as soon as I add a reference to my background (Entrypoint: `Background.BackgroundTask`), in the namespace `Background`, in the class `BackgroundTask`, assembly name & default namespace `Background` my project will refuse to build for release because `Internal compiler error: An item with the same key has already been added`. Debug still works 100%. I'm a bit lost as to why this is. Also, Background builds on it's own without any problems.

I have already tried uninstalling my app and running VS as admin. Clean/rebuild didn't help either, and using only these two Projects didn't make a difference. What else can I do?

Edit: For whatever reason, this problem only happens if Foreground has enabled Compile with .Net native toolchain, but I can't release it on the store without it. I was told I should try commenting out parts of the code - are there any specific parts that can cause this? Like should I focus on the imports, or specific functions?

My references for Foreground:

```
Analyzers 
Background 
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 
Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications 
Universal Windows 
Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP
```

Background:

```
Analyzers 
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 
Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications 
Universal Windows 
Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract
```

Comment: Show us the problematic code.  We can't help based on a description of the code.

Comment: @Amy What is the important part though? The manifest? It is a lot of code, and I don't know which is problematic. I only have the error message and the project it is coming from.

Comment: It is important to get a clean build from .NETNative, you can't get your app published otherwise.  It is a lousy non-descriptive error message, you need to tackle this by commenting out chunks of code.  Use Microsoft Support if you don't want to troubleshoot this yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant What chunks of code exactly? Just my methods? Or rather imports?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract`. Removing this reference solves the problem. Instead, `Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP` should be also added to background.

Answer (score -1):

1) In these cases only clean and rebuild all can help you. 
Its probable your Debug profile still kept some older (previously compiled assembly) version of one of projects and uses it for running (its only copied not rebuilt again). When you will Clean and Rebuild Debug, you will probably get as same error as you have on Release now.

2) When Clean and Rebuild commands will not help to you, try to create fully new projects and import *.cs files from current projects and again provide references.

3) Ensure you don't have a circular dependency in References of all projects (despite of you aren't notified for that by compiler now. Sometimes behavior of compiler is strange in this cases.)